# Create desktop shortcut after installation electron app

Tags: electron, electron-packager

How can I create shortcut after installation electron app using package "electron-wix-msi"?

Here is my MSI Creator

```
const msiCreator = new MSICreator({
  appDirectory: APP_DIR,
  outputDirectory: OUR_DIR,

  description: 'Application',
  exe: 'App',
  name: 'App',
  manufacturer: 'Publisher',
  version: '1.0.0',
  ui: {
    chooseDirectory: true,
  }
});
```

Comment: I've never used `electron-wix-msi` before so I may be mistaken, but is the `shortcutFolderName` option what you're after?

Comment: I have already tried it, but it is the name of the shortcut folder in the Windows Start Menu, not for Desktop.
Do you know another electron msi builder?

Comment: Yeah, I used to use [`electron-winstaller`](https://github.com/electron/windows-installer)